# View doesn't show same result as command with subquery on mariadb

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

Dears,

I tried to create a view that sumarize transaction per category (row) and months (columns) on one year as this :

```sql
SELECT counterpart.id_category as catid, category AS Category, (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0)
    FROM transaction
    INNER JOIN counterpart
        ON transaction.id_counterpart = counterpart.id_counterpart
    WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(now())
        AND MONTH(date) = 1
        AND id_category = catid
) AS Jan, [...]
FROM transaction
INNER JOIN counterpart
    ON transaction.id_counterpart = counterpart.id_counterpart
INNER JOIN category
    ON counterpart.id_category = category.id_category
WHERE transaction.id_user = 2
    AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(now())
GROUP BY category
```

I don't know if it's a good way or not, at least it works as single command but not as view.

On view, the `WHERE id_category = catid` for subquery doesn't work properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect conditional aggregation would be more appropriate and quicker than a lot of sub queries.

for example

```
SELECT counterpart.id_category as catid, category AS Category, 
sum(case when month(date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
sum(case when month(date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Mar
FROM transaction
INNER JOIN counterpart
    ON transaction.id_counterpart = counterpart.id_counterpart
INNER JOIN category
    ON counterpart.id_category = category.id_category
WHERE transaction.id_user = 2
    AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(now())
GROUP BY counterpart.id_category,category
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I just replaced `then 1` by `then amount` to have the sum. Thank you.